# Python: How do I convert an int to its string representation with a set number of digits?

Tags: python, string

Pretty much what it says up there.

Basically, how do I get the string produced by

```
print "%05d" % 100
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Maybe I'm misinterpreting the question, but this should work:

```
my_string = "%05d" % 100
```

Comment: Huh. Assumed that was part of the args to print. Nope. God, it's a beautiful language.

Comment: @deworde: It's even better if you read through a tutorial.  Seriously.  What tutorial are you using?

Comment: @S.Lott I'm looking at http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#strings right now.

And that doesn't tell you it's in there, and when it gives you an example in the reference notes, always uses print.

Comment: @deworde: Thanks. There's a "See Also" section that's relevant.  You might want to use http://diveintopython.org/native_data_types/formatting_strings.html instead.

Comment: @S.Lott Yes, that would be the reference notes I referred to, but as I said, always uses print in the examples.

Also, they're, as usual, in a style that means you have to know what you're looking for before you start looking. My favourite line, "The effect is similar to the using sprintf()  in the C language". I mean technically, that should have been helpful, but it does rather make an assumption.

Comment: @S.Lott Cheers for the link, though. V. helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Use str.zfill(width)

Comment: The URL for zfill is http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.zfill.  The % or format techniques are preferred.

Answer (score 1):

This should work too:

```
`100`.zfill(5)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print('{0:0=5d}'.format(100))
# 00100


    use the 0th positional argument to format
   /  fill character is '0'
  /  / desired width of formatted string
 /  / /
{0:0=5d}
```

For more, see [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-string-syntax).

Answer (score 1):

```
i = 100
str(i).zfill(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Python 3, the [str.format](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) method is preferred.  It was introduced in Python 2.6.  (Alas, my work system is at 2.4 (and I'm not permitted to upgrade), so I can't construct and test an example.)